# Specs of TPU on colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

How do I see specs of TPU on colab, for GPU I am able to use commands like

```
nvidia-smi
```

but it does not work for TPU, how do I get to see specs of TPU?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find the source. But it is said somewhere that Colab TPU is TPU v2-8.

See more details about TPU v2-8 (and others) here.

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tpus

Comment: Thanks for the link